# Especificar repetidos de una lista<T> C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un Excel donde guardo la siguiente información que voy a subir masivamente a una base de datos usando C#:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Antes de que el usuario pueda subir esto a la base de datos tengo que realizar un par de validaciones (orden exista, caja exista, etc.), una de las validaciones que quiero hacer es validar que los datos que ingrese no se repitan dentro del Excel (en la imagen de ejemplo la linea 3 se repite, ya que es pertenece a la misma caja-bolsa de la misma orden) para eso uso el siguiente codigo, el mismo se guarda en una DataTable y despues se convierte en List:

**Clase**

```
 public class MapaCargaEmpaque
    {
        public string Orden { get; set; }
        public int Caja { get; set; }
        public int Bolsa { get; set; }
    }
```

**Conversion a List**

```
     List<MapaCargaEmpaque> ListadoCarga = datatable.AsEnumerable().Select(m => new MapaCargaEmpaque()
     {
         Orden = Convert.ToString(m.Field<string>("Orden")),
         Caja = Convert.ToInt32(m.Field<string>("Caja").ToString()),
         Bolsa = Convert.ToInt32(m.Field<string>("Bolsa").ToString())
   }).ToList();
```

**Busca repetidos**

```
 var duplicates = ListadoCarga.GroupBy(ki => new {ki.Orden, ki.Caja, ki.Bolsa })
                  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                  .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Al corre ya el ultimo código y revisar el resultado veo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo modificar este código (o algo similar) que me diga que # de líneas fueron las repetidas, para poder decirle al usuario "la Linea #3-linea #5 están repetidas".

Comment: Puedes usar un diccionario o algo del estilo, que no permiten claves o elementos duplicados.

Comment: Edita la pregunta incluyendo los datos que creas que sean mínimos y necesarios para que cualquier usuario que desee apoyarte, pueda tener la facilidad de reproducir el escenario en el cual estás. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar la propiedad Fila a tu modelo, para indicar la fila en cuestión

```
public class MapaCargaEmpaque
{
    public int Fila { get; set; }
    public string Orden { get; set; }
    public int Caja { get; set; }
    public int Bolsa { get; set; }
}
```

```
int fila=1; //si es un excel con cabecera empezar del 2
List<MapaCargaEmpaque> ListadoCarga = datatable.AsEnumerable().Select(m => new MapaCargaEmpaque()
     {
         Fila =  fila++,
         Orden = Convert.ToString(m.Field<string>("Orden")),
         Caja = Convert.ToInt32(m.Field<string>("Caja").ToString()),
         Bolsa = Convert.ToInt32(m.Field<string>("Bolsa").ToString())
   }).ToList();
```

```
var duplicates = ListadoCarga.GroupBy(ki => new { ki.Orden, ki.Caja, ki.Bolsa })
                 .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                 .Select(g => "Filas repetidas : " + string.Join(" - ",g.Select(a=> "#" + a.Fila)));
```

Salida:

```
foreach (var l in ListadoCarga)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{l.Fila}  {l.Orden}  {l.Caja}  {l.Bolsa}");
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excelente, funciono, gracias.